# Easier way to link to another Stack Exchange site in comments? (e.g. auto-link names, or similar)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

When referring people to other Stack Exchange sites, usually in question comments, it's helpful to provide an actual link.

However, it's a pain to have to write `[Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)` or `[Prog.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)` or whatever.

Could we automatically link (first|any) occurrence of a site name made in a comment?

Or if not automatic, simply a shorter link so we don't need the extra fluff.

Perhaps a pseudo-protocol style, e.g. `[se:WebApps]` could be converted into:

```
<a href="http://webapps.stackexchange.com">
    <img src="webapps-site-icon.16x.png" />
    WebApps StackExchange
</a>
```

With the icon helping to draw attention to it as a Stack Exchange site.

I don't really mind how - so long as there's a way to be helpful to [new] users without spending unnecessary effort. So yeah, what does everyone else think?

Comment: How often do you need to link to other Stack Exchange Websites in actual post bodies? Here, maybe often enough, but elsewhere and especially on the parent sites this is more likely to be in comments, which are purposefully lightweight. This feels like it'll score very lowly on priority.

Comment: The other benefit of a shortcut is that you'll get less vague references such as "MSO" - most people here probably know that's referring to the central Meta site (here), but most newbies will just be confused by the acronym.

Comment: Grace, I'm talking about comments, not message bodies. I thought I'd mentioned that, but I've just made it clearer.

Comment: I was pointing out that since the primary utility would be in comments and there is little use in post bodies, and because comments are purposefully lightweight, this is probably going to score very lowly on priority.

Comment: There's a difference between "purposefully lightweight" and "feature locked".

This would not cause prolific commenting, so is not at odds with the "comments are discouraged" attitude, and it is almost certainly a trivial code change. (Share the code and I'll submit the patch myself.)

Comment: Just noticed the `[se:site]` style is consistent with how tag linking is done - so there's presumably already suitable code in place - probably with icons too (given the sponsored tag stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things like `[programmers.se]` and `[so]` work now; see [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000).

Comment: Any idea why this is only in comments, and not in actual posts as well?

Answer (score 1):

I like this idea, but I wonder if what we really need is more migration options. Once a related site (like Programmers) is out of beta, we should be able to close as "belongs on".

Comment: It's useful to refer to sites whilst still in beta though - the idea of "belongs on" working with beta sites has already been rejected though. :(

Comment: Also, I sometimes refer to other sites *without* an accompanying close vote (and/or when I might want to suggest multiple sites).

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to refer to sites without the intent of migration (at Gaming, we do it every now and then with AskUbuntu). And sometimes, there really isn't enough need to warrant the construction of a migration bridge from one site to another, but a question gets asked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are of course client-side workarounds such as [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/) and [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Those are client-side *workarounds* - and, as on my comment above, it'd have a good side-effect of cutting down internal references which are not helpful for newbies and search-based visitors.