# Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, chat, magic-links

Ask yourself how many times you typed the following in a *comment*:

```
[meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com)
```

Me, personally, I'm sick of it. Can we have some *data.stackexchange.com*-style "magic links" in comments?  (inn~iff)

Comment: Very, very good idea, especially the FAQ#name one.

Comment: Why inn? At least on meta they'd be very useful in answers

Comment: Instead of alternate forms (as you have for [edit]), why not provide generic text? [edit "edit it"] [faq#bounty "Read about bounties in the FAQ"]

Comment: Don't see the need for combining [user:] with notification.

Comment: Requiring a colon in the syntax is less likely to have false positives.  Instead of [so] and [x.se], use [site:XXX] where XXX is SO, SU, SF, or the subdomain of SE.  [faq:all] and [faq:section] work, but that leaves nothing for [edit] except [edit:], which I dislike. Maybe [link:] instead of [site:], then you can include "faq", "meta", and "edit" in [link:].

Comment: @fred no, you type [@fred] (*like* user notification) and it turns into a link - [Fred Nurk](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/153553/fred-nurk).

Comment: I've actually never typed that in a comment. Then again, I'm not a mod...

Comment: Oh super super! I love you with totality and Tootsie-Rolls. With our collective saved-time we shall ascend to Mars, Pluto, and Milky.

Comment: "Ask yourself how many times you typed the following in a Comment"  - Never :^)
I often link to some other sites though - in migration suggestions.

Comment: Sort of magic for URLs themselves (e.g., `current` for the current user instead of a fixed user ID): *[Documentation for Stack Exchange engine URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332237/)* and *[List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/)*

Answer (score 454, accepted):

Most of these now work. My comment below has the following markdown source:

> On [main], you are expected to write proper English (as advertised on [english.se]), but here on [meta.se] it's more important to have freehand circles, so please [edit] your post, otherwise I'll have to flag you (see the [FAQ#flagging]). If you're unsure how to use your keyboard, [su] is the right place to ask. There's no Q&A site about unicorns yet, but you can suggest one on [area51.se].

---

### Magic Links

- Characters within the magic links can be any mix of upper and lower case. Some, but not all, of the magic links will respect the case used in the magic link and use the same case for the link text. This is noted in the entry for those which respect case.
- On localized sites, the link text for each of the below magic links is localized.

#### Supported magic links in comments

- `[meta]` – links to the current site's Meta; link text is the site name (e.g. "Meta Super User"). Does nothing if the site doesn't have (or already is) a Meta site.
- `[main]` – like [meta], just the other way around (i.e. it doesn't work on main sites; only works on meta sites which have an associated main site).
- `[edit]` – links to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e. /posts/{id}/edit. Link text is "edit" (capitalization is respected).
- Help center links.  Link text for all of these is "help center":

  - `[help]` – links to the help center (/help).
  - `[meta-help]` – links to "What is meta?" (/help/whats-meta)
  - `[help/on-topic]` – links to "What topics can I ask about here?" (/help/on-topic).
  - `[help/dont-ask]` – links to "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" (/help/dont-ask).
  - `[help/behavior]` – links to "What kind of behavior is expected of users?" (/help/behavior).
- `[tour]` or `[about]` – links to (<main site>/tour). Link text is "tour" (capitalization is respected). Legacy magic link `[about]` is still supported.
- `[meta-tour]` or `[meta-about]` – links to (<meta site>/tour). These only work on meta sites. Link text is "tour" (capitalization is respected). Legacy magic link `[meta-about]` is still supported.
- `[ask]` – links to the "How to Ask" page. Link text is "How to Ask".
- `[what you are asking]` – links to the "How to Ask" page. Link text is "what you are asking".
- `[answer]` – links to the "How to Answer" page. Link text is "How to Answer".
- Links to the front page of Stack Exchange sites (link text is the site name):

  - `[so]` – links to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
  - `[su]` – links to [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
  - `[sf]` – links to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
  - `[metase]`/`[meta.se]` – links to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)
  - `[ubuntu.se]` – links to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)
  - `[mathoverflow.se]` – links to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)
  - `[a51]` – links to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com)
  - `[se]` – links to the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/)
  - Localized Stack Overflow sites can be linked as

    - `[es.so]` – links to [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)
    - `[ja.so]` – links to [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
    - `[pt.so]` – links to [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)
    - `[ru.so]` – links to [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)
  - All other Stack Exchange sites, except Stack Apps:

    - `[something.se]` – links to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name.
    - `[sitename.meta.se]` or `[meta.sitename.se]` – links to a site-specific Meta site. Link text is "Meta <sitename>".
- `[chat]` – links to the current site's chat site (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ for SO, https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ for Meta SE, https://chat.stackexchange.com/ everywhere else – that last one showing a list of active rooms from the referring site), the link text being "{site name} Chat".
- `[code block]` – links to the "Code and Preformatted Text" section of the Markdown Editing Help page (/editing-help#code). Link text is "code block".
- On Stack Overflow only:

  - `[English-only site]` – links to the (SO-only) Help Center page "[Can I ask a question in a language other than English?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions)". Link text is "English-only site".
  - `[help/sg]` – links to the (SO-only) Help Center page "[What is the Staging Ground?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-is-staging-ground)". Link text is "What is the Staging Ground?".
- On Stack Overflow and localized Stack Overflow sites (these do not work on the associated meta sites):

  - `[mcve]`, `[reprex]`, `[repro]`, `[mre]` and `[example]` – links to the [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) page for the site. Link text is "minimal reproducible example", or localized text on localized sites. Capitalization doesn't matter and is not respected.
- Links to specific tags. These work in questions, answers, comments, and chat – but in comments, they are just formatted like regular links, rather than appearing like tags. Link text is just the name of the tag. These will link to the specified tag, regardless of whether the tag actually exists:

  - `[tag:tag-name]` creates a link to the named tag on the main site, e.g [tag-name](/questions/tagged/tag-name). (Whether it's used on the main site or the meta site, the link will point to a tag on the main site.)
  - `[meta-tag:meta-tag-name]` creates a link to a tag on meta, e.g [meta-tag-name](/questions/tagged/meta-tag-name). (Whether it's used on the main site or the meta site, the link will point to a tag on the meta site.)
  - (On Meta Stack Exchange, which doesn't have a main site, `[tag:tag-name]` and `[meta-tag:tag-name]` work exactly the same way.)

#### Supported magic links in chat

In chat, only a limited subset of the magic links listed for comments work, plus one chat-specific magic link.

Chat supports the following magic links: `[meta]`, `[main]`, `[ask]`, `[answer]`, all the links to specific sites, and tag links (with tag formatting). Chat also adds `[chat-faq]`, which results in a link to /faq on the current chat database, with the link text "chat faq" (e.g. "[chat faq](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq)").

The tag magic links work as expected on [Stack Overflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and [Meta Stack Exchange Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/). However, on [Stack Exchange Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/), the chat room in which you use the magic link must be associated with a specific Stack Exchange site, and will take on the formatting of tags on that site. When the room is not associated with a specific Stack Exchange site, the text used for the tag magic link receives no special processing.

#### Supported magic links in questions and answers

On main sites, only the `[tag:tag-name]` and `[meta-tag:meta-tag-name]` magic links are supported in questions and answers. The `[meta-tag:meta-tag-name]` magic links will be rendered when the post is saved, but do not display as a tag in the post preview while editing.

On meta sites, only the `[tag:tag-name]` and `[meta-tag:meta-tag-name]` magic links are supported in questions and answers.

All of the other magic links are not supported in questions and answers.

Comment: On [main], you are expected to write proper English (as advertised on [english.se]), but here on [metase] it's more important to have freehand circles, so please [edit] your post, otherwise I'll have to flag you (see the [FAQ#flagging]). If you're unsure how to use your keyboard, [su] is the right place to ask. There's no Q&A site about unicorns yet, but you can suggest one on [area51.se].

Comment: Very nice, but what about user pages and links to specific posts? Like [main#12345] or [meta.user#12345]...

Comment: @fretje: Nope, we're not doing that. It'll take longer to copy the id out of the URL into your `[main#...]` markup than just copying the whole link. (Besides that, there's also a technical reason: Comments are rendered on the fly, so you'd have to do a DB lookup everytime such a comment is displayed)

Comment: @balpha: Ok, I understand... It would be nice though if \[so]/q/12345 would work then... (this doesn't need a db lookup, right)

Comment: @fretje: Do you really have the ids of posts you frequently link to memorized?

Comment: I don't, but I'm sure some of us do, this would actually be an incentive to *start* learning them by heart... ;-)

Comment: And apparently my above comment doesn't work... even the [so] only hasn't been "translated"... I suppose that's because there have to be spaces around it... could you also translate when there's a '/' after it?

Comment: @fretje: It did work, actually -- I edited it (put a backslash to before the bracket).

Comment: Oh, ok, just to test then: [so]/q/6254529

Comment: Oops... not as I had in mind... Ok, but I understand adding "/q/6254529" to the url would be easy, but then the problem would be what to put as the link text? In that case you could simply expand the url to http://stackoverflow.com/q/6254529 but that might make this feature indeed be too "complex". I was just thinking out loud... forgive me ;-)

Comment: On an unrelated note though... this does mean that the [editing help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) will have to be updated again.

Comment: Yay! Two more requests: `[how-to-ask]`, `[how-to-answer]` (and the anchored versions [when they're created](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89440/add-anchors-to-the-how-to-ask-and-how-to-answer-pages)).

Comment: How does this now affect comment length? Are they stored in the db and rendered on the page or are they pre-rendered before storing?

Comment: @jcolebrand: the former

Comment: And [user:@balpha] adds more awesome to SE :)

Comment: I'd like to put something in the [meta-tag:faq] about this.  You think I should ask a new question about how to use magic links, or just wait until after the bounty and convert this one?  (also, bug report:  edit this comment and look at the link for the faq--meta-tag doesn't prevent the magic link from being created)

Comment: @Won't: Uhm what now? Looks as expected to me. `[meta-tag:faq]` links to the... meta tag `[faq]`.

Comment: @balpha: whoops, my bad.  Never mind on that.  What about the initial question on whether to convert this to a faq entry or wait until the bounty completes?  Also, why is there a bounty?

Comment: @Won't: Because we're still taking suggestions for additional magic links. And Jeff had a few reps to spare :)

Comment: I want to see this syntax: [metaso:92060#94000] because once you've got the bit going, you can hash the URL and you can snag the postid out of there as well.

Comment: The site-links are nice, but inconsistent: why don't `[superuser.se]` ([superuser.se]) and `[askubuntu.se]` ([askubuntu.se]) generate links? Sure, `[su]` ([se]) and `[ubuntu.se]` ([ubuntu.se]) work, but why do I have to remember these special cases? Thanks!

Comment: Could we also have [stackapps] (or [stackapps.se], or even [sa]), please?

Comment: Hey, just found myself wanting [stackapps].  Poor, stackapps, it gets no love.

Comment: Can we puhhlllease have `[mso]` instead of `[metaso]`? Or `[meta.so]`? No one remembers the `[metaso]`, it doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Better idea from @slhck's comment: ALL OF THEM. They're all distinct.

Comment: damnit @balpha ... gimme [meta] on meta's, please?

Comment: Seconded @jcolebrand suggestion, `[meta]` and `[main]` should work on either site regardless.  I ran into this situation yesterday, it's more common than you think.  A tweak here would be appreciated.

Comment: Mostly I just like it because it saves me untold keystrokes when I want to reference the difference between `[main] vs [meta]` but have the names there. The auto-expansion is what I really want. Think "ReSharper for Comments" as that's what I use these short-links for. As you can see, several of us do.

Comment: Related: [Add a markdown shortcut to Ask a New Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139298/add-a-markdown-shortcut-to-ask-a-new-question)

Comment: I noticed that `[faq]` now redirects to the help center. Is there a correct magic link for that yet?

Comment: @Ullallulloo See [Replace \[faq\] magiclink with \[help\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183131/replace-faq-magiclink-with-help)

Comment: Can we add `[sites]` (to http://stackexchange.com/sites obviously)?

Comment: Perhaps add [/help/editing]? (Requires move from /editing-help to /help/editing).

Comment: Is there a magic link for discuss.area51?

Comment: Hey, [meta.so] and [careers] should be added.  Thanks!

Comment: What, you don't want to link to [meta.so]?  I mean, look at that!  It's just sitting there, waiting to be implemented!

Comment: Is the list of magic links to help center complete (just want to know)?

Comment: It has a bug, these magic links ignore a valid link which is inserted in the parenthesis as I raised it here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296835/pointing-to-a-wrong-address-for-the-link-inserted-in-the-comments

Comment: @balpha are there any plans to add [stackapps]?? If not, is there somewhere to go to request it?? Other than starting an entire new feature-request?

Comment: You might want to somehow avoid that people use this feature to create comments like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment860283_3122) (I intentionally deleted the comment).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft This came up a couple of times (now deleted), both in the sandbox and in this very comment thread. Since it doesn't create a real problem (other than being slightly annoying) and is undone quickly (a moderator will just delete the comment and give you a slap on the wrist if you continuously do stuff like that), adding additional rules would just be extra work and create extra edge cases with very little gain.

Comment: A lot of the magic links still have a default name, as [my recent, quickly upvoted question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305847/suggestion-for-distinguished-link-text-of-help-help-on-topic-help-dont-as/305928#305928) and [this older question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261301/make-help-center-magic-link-anchor-text-more-unique-and-descriptive) show, there's a lot of request for making links like `[help/on-topic]` be more descriptive than just "[help/on-topic]". If this could be implemented on top of what you guys already did, that'd be a great plus!

Comment: PS, interesting to see that `[main]` doesn't work anymore, as your first comment in this thread shows.

Comment: @Abel This answer was posted on Meta Stack Overflow before Meta Stack Exchange existed. MSO has a main site, MSE does not.

Comment: Some of these links aren't working in chat: `[tour]`, `[help]`, `[help/on-topic]`, … (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25771792#25771792). Was that an intended change?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274240/215590 is asking for [meta.so] to be implemented.

Comment: Why doesn't `[help/formatting]` work to link http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting?

Comment: `[tag:tag-name]` such as `[tag:feature-request]` creates a link to the named tag, such as [tag:feature-request].

Comment: It would be nice to have a link to the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for posts where the OP doesn't seem to know how to use markdown.

Comment: [mcve] would be so helpful on [dba.se]

Comment: Can we have a magic link specific for the community? e.g I want [guidelines] refers to [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/277) for the community I moderate.

Comment: I think `[mcve]` should be available SE-wide. In addition to @MaxVernon's request for Database Administrators, I feel it would be useful for Arduino, Raspberry Pi, Robotics, IOT... among many others.

Comment: What about [help/how-to-ask] ?

Comment: Do links to child-metas of [ubuntu.se] and [mathoverflow.se] work? Looks like only `[meta.ubuntu.se]` works: [meta.ubuntu.se], [meta.mathoverflow.se], [ubuntu.meta.se], [mathoverflow.meta.se], [meta.mo.se], [mo.meta.se], [mo], [meta.mo], [meta.ubuntu]. See [Magic link for MathOverflow in chat and comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301138/289905#comment1084171_301139).

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur There’s the much shorter `[ask]`.

Comment: Some of this is now on the [Markdown help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) page.

Comment: [:)] - no, doesn't work, darnit ;)

Answer (score 61):

I would still like an
`[accept]` which would link to [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 60):

#### Edit

Some more ideas, since this seems to be still active.

Maybe it could also be useful to add things like:

- `[dupe:92060]` for "possible duplicate of "
- `[inbox]`
- `[review]`, but I think this is marginal
- `[privilege:name]` to link to a specific privilege description

#### History

I think this idea can be improved in a generic way like:

[`SITE`:`type`:`id#anchor`]

Where

- `SITE` is SF, SO, SU, meta, metaSU with default to the current site
- `type` can be user, post, faq with default to post
- `anchor/id` can be the id of a post, of an user and anchor a HTML anchor like in the FAQ, or a comment, or a anwser.

You can only use default values from the left. If you specify `SITE` you have to specify all.

So on this post:

- `[92060]` would link to `[meta:post:92060]`
- `[92060#answer-92061]` would link to my answer (need way to identify the answer's numbers)
- `[SU:post:286219]` would link to [Unix : List children processes for a given pid](https://superuser.com/questions/286219/unix-list-children-processes-for-a-given-pid)
- `[user:1228]` will link to the user with ID equal to 1228 on meta
- `[SO:user:1228]` will link to the user with ID equal to 1228 on Stack Overflow
- `[SO:faq:#bounty]` on the "bounty" section of the SO's FAQ

Comment: I especially like the privilege and dupe idea.

Comment: I'd really like to link to specific posts, especially on meta. Would be super handy in executing moderator duties. Prefer syntax of `[meta:92060]` or `[main:667]`.

Comment: Did these extra suggestions get implemented? I think they would make writing comments on [se] more convenient.

Comment: @Alex I do not think so. If it's not in balpha's answer it's probably not implemented.

Comment: Too bad. It's unfortunate that these very handy shortcuts weren't implemented.

Comment: @AlexEssilfie and M'vy, if you're still interested, I've made a userscript that implements the site:type:id magic link idea: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278421/260841 :)

Answer (score 34):

In addition to `[so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, etc. I would suggest adding `[careers]` with link text of "Stack Overflow Careers".

Answer (score 23):

A chat room link could be useful I think.

```
[chat:ROOM_ID]
```

This wouldn't be that useful, more like a fun thing, linking to yourself.

```
[self]
```

Comment: `[self]` or `[this]`? :)

Comment: Semantically `[self]` would make more sense in my opinion. :)

Comment: `[this]` would refer to the current chat room or comment in my weird logic. :D

Comment: I would prefer [this] for linking on the chat room and [self] for linking on myself.

Comment: `[chat:ROOM_NAME]` might also be useful

Comment: `[me]` would be quicker and more IRC-esque.  Though less obvious to OO programmers ;D

Comment: @Merlin `[me]` would be a link to your SO or chat.SO profile.

Comment: What language is the `this` joke referring to? Pardon my ignorance..

Comment: @DaniSpringer `this.edited == false`

Comment: @haykam I still don't know what language that is

Comment: @DaniSpringer `this.jokes[0].language == 'JavaScript'`

Comment: @haykam so its JS? What is the equivalent in python? `.self`?

Comment: @DaniSpringer `this.programming.languages.indexOf('Python') == -1`

Comment: @haykam hmm. I don't get it. Perhaps I need to refine my python...

Comment: @DaniSpringer `this.parent.givenUp == true`

Comment: I didn't know there can be more than one period. I thought there are classes and instances, and that's it. If `parent` is a class, what is `this`?

Answer (score 21):

This would save a lot of keystrokes:

```
[mcve] = [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
```

It would mostly be used on Stack Overflow, as I don't think many users of *[English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour)* would find much use for this, but it would be useful for any programming-related Stack Exchange site.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Note this is available now in [so].

Answer (score 12):

From the meta sites, I think we most often want to link to the FAQ of the main site, not of the meta site.

Can we have a magic link along the lines of `[mainfaq#dontask]`?

Comment: Alternatively, do it just like we do with tags - have `[faq]` link the Main one, and `[meta-faq]` link the Meta one, whether you're on Main or Meta.

Comment: We're going with @GraceNote's suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not convinced that new Markdown syntax is needed. This could be handled by having a better interface to insert these links.

There are already a few of useful user scripts in this domain:

- [Pro-forma comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/pro-forma-comments): surely every moderator has it already?
- [Copy Question Link Markdown - Making it easier to copy links to questions!](https://stackapps.com/questions/2150/copy-question-link-markdown-making-it-easier-to-copy-links-to-questions), or [Comment Link AutoPrettifier](https://stackapps.com/questions/2378/comment-link-autoprettifier), either of which could be extended to cope with links other than questions.

Comment: Programmers are always fond of mardown. It's like command line over GUI: faster.

Comment: @M'vy: 1. Stack Exchange isn't specifically for programmers. 2. I'm more of a command-line advocate than the average programmer, and I still think we don't need more markdown here. 3. Just because every problem can be solved by adding a level of indirection doesn't mean it's the best way.

Comment: Yes of course. I got your point. Nevertheless, when I answer on my mobile phone as an example... GUI stinks. I already have some difficulties to validate my anwsers. Or copy/pasting isn't easy as well. So if I can avoid doing this by typing instead, I'm in.

Answer (score 6):

The userscript [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/29559) supports creating **customized** magic link into **posts**:

[image]

Use the placeholders `$BASEURL`, `$METABASEURL`, `$QUESTIONID`, and `$ANSWERID` in the URL.

You can also use it to change the help button to link to the on-topic page:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A lot of the answers under [What sites should have hyperlinking (onebox) support in chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57288/what-sites-should-have-hyperlinking-onebox-support-in-chat) would also be good here. Perhaps some could be site-specific; the English Language and Usage folks probably don't link to MSDN very often.

Answer (score 5):

The following magic link types have been added and can be found in the list [above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/1220372): `[code block]`, `[english-only site]`, `[what you are asking]` and `[help/sg]`.

Answer (score 4):

Some more for the melting pot:

`[#12345]` for questions

`[me]` to link to users profile in chat

`[chat:ROOM_NAME_OR_ID]` for linking to chat rooms

`@USERNAME` twitter-style user tags which currently work in chat but not comments

Comment: the first has been declined (see the comments on my answer); for the second and third see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94355#94355 (although both are unlikely to happen); the fourth does work very well: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply

Comment: it would be very handy to have something like `[chat:android]` but I understand that these are trying to be kept to a minimuum.  Thanks for the link to comment-reply.  That is getting bookmarked ;)

Comment: ... and the equivalent id version using `#`

 i.e [chat#15] is equivalent to `[chat:android]`.

Answer (score 2):

## External manuals

Some sites need to systematically reference and link to external documentation and people may be reasonably worried to follow non-standards links.

For example, in the *"mathematica.stackexchange.com"* site, links to the Wolfram Mathematica functions documentation are often needed, the users need to do

`['InputForm'](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/InputForm.html)`

were the only variable part is the function name.

This could be easily replaced by `[rw:InputForm]`

Similarly, in *"rpg.stackexchange.com"* they often link to

`[Find Familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar)`

which also has only one variable region on the link and could be easily a magic link  like `[spell:find-familiar]`

## Questions and answers

Also, as suggested by @Moog, Magic links to questions are often needed. I would favour the syntax

`[q:11350]` to be a shortcut to `['InputForm'](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-plotsl)`

or `[q:92060]` a link to this question.