# Can we get a [main:chat] comment tag for use on Meta?

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

The [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) are awesome but linking to `[chat]` while on Meta Stack Overflow only points to the Meta.SO Chat. It would be handy to be able to link to the Stack Overflow chat in comments on Meta Stack Overflow.

(I don't care about formatting but my first guess was `[main:chat]`.)

---

Since apparently there is no "English Language and Usage Meta Chat", is there a reason it includes "Meta" in the link?

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow are the only sites with their own individual chat sites. Everything else - Super User, Server Fault, all of the SE 2.0 sites, and all of the Metas for each of these named - is at `chat.stackexchange.com`, and that is where the `[chat]` link will point to.

Main/Meta chat links possess very limited utility as a result, since the majority of sites will link to the exact same site for both the Meta and the Main. If it was necessary, it may be better to have it in a fashion of `[so:chat]`, `[mso:chat]`, and `[se:chat]`, with `[chat]` retaining its behavior as a default. I think it's still a little exclusive, but I think that way will be a bit more useful than a "redundant in all but two sites" implementation.

Comment: They'd be redundant now, but things could change and other sites could get their own chats. The `[main:chat]` form would be more future-proof

Comment: @bemace As it were, the preferable "future" in my eyes would be "We just have one chat site", rather than "We all get our own individual chat sites when many sites barely use more than one room, for both Meta and Main". We already tried the "One chat per site" back with Web Apps and Gaming (and possibly Web Masters). It proved to be very ineffective, so I wouldn't recommend encouraging its return through that kind of implementation.

Comment: Heh, good to know. In that case, can we remove the Meta label from a chat link that doesn't point to a distinct meta chat?