# Link to questions in comments and posts

Tags: discussion, questions, hyperlinks

I recently discovered you could link to tags like [this](/questions/tagged/this). Is there a similarly simple way I can link to questions? If not, maybe adding this could be cool? For example `[q:19]` could turn into a link like this:

[Fastest way to get value of pi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19).

Answer (score 4):

For questions and answers you may post just the URL and it will be replaced as a link with the question name.

It's more useful than your request because you seldom know the question ID, but it's easy to copy and paste a full link to a question.

(This does not work in comments, but comments do have [a set of magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) that are converted into real links.)

Comment: And this gives [the full link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19/fastest-way-to-get-value-of-pi), which I like much better than just `http://stackoverflow.com/q/19`. A full link not only saves a trip to the web server to get [a 302 Found](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F19) (or [a 301 Moved Permanently](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F19%2Fsome-other-title) if SE is not expecting a referral link), but also ensures you're not actually messing around and directing to something else. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, it was in a comment it happened. Got a link with dots rather than the name of the question. Like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103347/link-to-questions-in-comments-and-posts