# Magic Links to questions within comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

I'm a big fan of the [Magic Links in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000). Heck, I'm going to wear out my *f*, *a*, and *q* keys shortly after I wear out *[* and *]*.

I very often find myself putting links to other questions (and answers) in comments to draw people's attention to similar and related posts but which aren't duplicates. Yes, I can just paste a raw link and that will work fine. It's not very **readable**, though.

In Questions and Answers, posting a raw link to a Stack Exchange post anywhere in the network will replace the raw link to a linkified title. There was a [feature request to have the same sort of functionality in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59558/make-links-to-other-questions-display-better-in-comments), but it was more-or-less quashed as a [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56364/auto-replace-sofu-links-with-their-title) of the [request for this feature in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title), even though it's for comments.

Lacking that functionality, I wonder if it would be possible to expand on the Magic Links for comments to include Post IDs.

In other words, a comment like:

```
See also: [11227809]
```

would automagically expand to

```
See also: [Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809)
```

when saved.

I suppose some extra magic would have to be done to get a meta question linked just so.

Note that I'm only proposing that this Magic work on the current site, not that it should attempt to do anything across the network. Posting links to questions on other sites is rare enough that doing it the old-fashioned way is no big deal.

([This was asked about in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103347/link-to-questions-in-comments-and-posts), but it was just a question if it could be done. This is an actual feature request.)

Comment: Until this is implemented, you can use this very handy userscript to do this for you right now: [Comment Link AutoPrettifier](http://stackapps.com/q/2378). Note that I already use this script, so all I had to do was paste the StackApps link into this comment. :-) It only works with full URLs (though `http://siteurl/q/1234` short links work fine), but it can link to *any* SE post with ease.

Comment: Related: [Userscript to auto-replace SOFU links in comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89378)

Comment: Related: [Replace links with the current question title in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394)

Comment: @Martijn: Well, isn't that something. Thanks. I'll need to install it on all the computers where I connect to Stack Exchange. And adding userscripts to Chrome isn't as easy as it used to be. But this should be helpful. Would rather see it as a built-in feature, though.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: you can take ideas from [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146274/link-shortcut-for-wikipedia#comment418705_146274) (but [note that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146274/link-shortcut-for-wikipedia#comment418831_146274) the `[u:userN]` should be `[u:userID]` instead)