# Why aren't links in comments replaced with the name of the question?

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

When I post the link to a Stack Overflow question in this question, the name of the link is converted to the title of the question:

[Get all possible matches for regex (in python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383818/get-all-possible-matches-for-regex-in-python)

When I post the same link in a comment (as shown below), it is displayed as a bare URL, which makes it harder to read.

Automatically including the name of the question makes these links easier to read, but it appears that links in comments don't automatically display the question's title. The readability of these links would be much improved if the names of the questions were automatically generated.

Comment: Links are shown in comments as bare URLs, unfortunately. This is the same link that I posted above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383818/get-all-possible-matches-for-regex-in-python

Comment: Also related: [Magic Links to questions within comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147729)

Comment: If the question title is longer than the URL - or maybe even not, depending on how the text gets stored, say if it's converted to the standard comment link format of `[title](url)` - it has the potential to push the comment over the length limit. I'm sure this could be checked against, but I suspect completely eliminating the edge case would be tricky.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName In that case, the question's title could be automatically shortened in order to fit within the length limit, using JavaScript's `string.substring` method.

Comment: @AndersonGreen That wouldn't be adequate for cases where there are only a few characters to spare. You might end up with something like "see this question: H", or worse, not have enough room to add any of the title at all.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName In that case, bare links could be used whenever there wasn't enough space to fit in the question's title. That would eliminate the problem completely.

Comment: @Esoteric, you seem to think the max length is a technical limit? I'm quite sure links are not replaced just because comments are rendered (converted into HTML) on the fly, and not cached such as the HTML of posts (which is converted from Markdown into HTML only once). Adding all kind of fancy stuff on comments also means more load on the server.

Comment: @Toomai & Anderson, despite the title of this very question: as both [Replace links with the current question title in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments) and this very post are feature requests, I feel this one is a dupe indeed.