# Where are the link shortcuts documented?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks, documentation

I've been searching around for this for a while now. I know I read somewhere that you can use

```
[cstheory.se]
```

as a shortcut to insert the following link

> [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com).

and similar for other Stack Exchange sites. However, I was wondering if this, and the other link shortcuts such as `[faq]` are documented anywhere, or if I just happened to read the answer to a feature request for this. I honestly cannot remember.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This functionality is documented in [balpha's implementation details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000), as well as in the expanded [Comment Formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) section of the advanced help which is accessible through the "Learn more" link on comment help, and the "advanced help" link on post Markdown help (<sub>[image: markdown help button]</sub>).

Comment: Oh splendid.  I didn't know about the Comment Formatting page.

Comment: And here I was searching around for it on meta when it was right in the place it should be all along. Oh well.

Comment: Wow, that Markdown help has improved a lot! Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94000)