# A definitive list of "Magic Link" Shortcuts for Comment markup

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add data.SE style “magic links” to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments)
>   [Where are the link shortcuts documented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104305/where-are-the-link-shortcuts-documented)

I found some information about magic links in the answer to [Add data.SE style “magic links” to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000), however I do not know if this list is exhaustive.  Additionally, some useful suggestions were made in subsequent answers and comment which are of significant value to high activity users.  I would be interested in knowing if any of these have since been implemeted.

I have tagged this as feature-request to highlight the other suggestions in the link I posted and  to request that any additional magic links be documented in the FAQ.  Feel free to retag as appropriate.

So in closing, is there a definitive list of magic links that are currently in-use on [SO]?

Comment: [balpha's answer is the definitive list.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments)

Answer (score 3):

This is  what I was looking for:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

I have had some feedback on the other suggestions.  They are unlikely to happen, although I did learn some new tricks from the linked wiki page :)