# Shortened URL for popular SE blog posts?

Tags: feature-request, s.tk, s.tk-request

I find myself fairly often wanting to refer someone to or review the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) post on the [Stack Overflow Blog](http://s.tk/blog).  I know there's at least one or two other posts that have other such useful nuggets of wisdom.  Could we get s.tk links for these?  For example, the aforementioned post could be `http://s.tk/subjective` or `http://s.tk/blog/subjective`.

If anyone has suggestions for other posts that should be included, please feel free to comment or edit this question to include them.

P.S.:  I'm also proposing this particular link via http://s.tk/linkrequest, but also wanted to make this question to hopefully inspire SEI to look into similarly significant blog posts that would be worth including.

Comment: What about a [magic comment link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) [subjective] that does the same?