# What do SO, SF and SU stand for?

Tags: support, questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

I'm new to the meta site, and this seems like a very simple question, but as I don't know the answer and google doesn't help i'm going to ask it anyway!

SO, SF and SU are mentioned in many questions and answers on the meta site, but what do these acronyms mean?

Comment: Note that sometimes, you'll even see SOFU.

Comment: SO is Stack Overflow, SF is San Francisco, SU is Soviet Union

Comment: Note that you can use these as [magic links in comments and chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000): `[so]` is automagically transformed to  [so], `[su]` -> [su], and `[sf]` -> [sf].

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- [**S**tack **O**verflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
- [**S**erver **F**ault](http://serverfault.com)
- [**S**uper **U**ser](http://superuser.com)

and as a bonus: MSO is this site, [**M**eta **S**tack **O**verflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Where these the first of the stack Exchange sites?  I'm just wondering why these sites are referenced with respect to reputation cross site privileges, yet the cooking site is not! It could of course just be what the authors of the questions thought important.

Comment: @AidanO Yup, they're the first and the largest. They're referred to as the [Stack Overflow Trilogy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/).

Comment: @AidanO - Yep, *the trilogy* as they are called were the originals!

Comment: @AidanO With respect to cross-site privileges: there shouldn't be anything different about these sites from the others. Either the post was written before the other sites were launched, or the author was just being selective. (Tiny exception: Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow have separate rep systems, while the other metas just inherit reputation from their parent sites.)

Comment: and SOFU is Stack|Server|Super Overflow Fault User

Comment: @Aidano - it probably is a bit of both "first" and "poster thinks they're more important" (note that I'm not saying the poster is right!). I know lots of "geeks who cook", and a few geeks that cycle and a few geeks who enjoy DIY and so on, on this group of sites but very few "cooks that geek", if that makes sense, and while that might just reflect that I'm antisocial and don't talk to enough people, I suspect that a lot of us came for one or more of the main sites and consider those the heart of the thing.