# Add a "magic link" markdown shortcut to Ask a New Question

Tags: feature-request, comments, asking-questions, magic-links

I notice often enough that I or someone else has to suggest asking a new question (especially to newer users) when discussion in comment threads gets too off topic.

I request an addition to the markdown shortcuts such as `[edit]` and `[faq]` that would link to `currentsite.stackexchange.com/questions/ask`. I realize that `[ask]` is already taken, so how about `[newq]`?

Comment: Because [newq] is a [newb] turned upside down. ...well the b anyway

Comment: @BenBrocka Wouldn't that be [newp]?

Comment: @DoubleAA ¿[bmau] for the australians