# Allow comment markdown shortcuts in (meta?) questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks, posting

## Background

I've thought about this on several occasions and always assumed someone already asked for it, but I can't find any duplicates.

In comments (and on chat), we can use some handy little markdown shortcuts to link to specific sites.

> `[so]`, `[pt.so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metase]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – link to the given site. Link text is the site name.
>
> `[something.se]` – link to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name. Use [ubuntu.se] for Ask Ubuntu.

That's great for times when we want to mention other sites. For instance, if I wrote,

> This might be more on-topic on [startups.se].

that would render out as,

> This might be more on-topic on [Startups Stack Exchange](http://startups.stackexchange.com).

Cool!

## Feature Request

I'd like to see this feature implemented in posts (questions and answers), particularly here on meta.

## Justification

The most obvious example comes in [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) questions. If I want to answer and suggest [Ask Patents](http://patents.stackexchange.com), it would be nice if I didn't have to type out the full name and URL:

```
[Ask Patents](http://patents.stackexchange.com)
```

But there are even other times when I'd like this. There was a question here on MSE a little while back where someone wanted to aggregate all of Stack Exchange into one site with a series of tags, and my answer to that involved referencing a number of sites.

I don't see any reason to restrict this to meta, though. I can imagine posting an answer on another site:

> ...
> This is illustrated well on this `[other question](link)` on `[site name](link)`.
> ...

## Benefits

The main benefit here is time. On top of the basic "typing `[so]` is faster than *[all that link text]*," I always worry that I'll have some typo in the link, so I end up typing the link, then copying it into a new tab to double-check it. If I could just know that what I typed would be typo-free, that would be far easier.

This is much less important, but it could also have an advantage when Stack Exchange eventually converts to 100% SSL traffic and all these existing links wind up pointing to the `http` version. There's a 301, which takes time and server resources. Again, a very small deal, but if we did have built-in links like these, we could easily inject the https version.

Not to mention, again not super important, promoting cross-pollination between sites is (sometimes) good! I consider this a pretty low-priority advantage, since I don't really foresee more people linking between sites just because of it, but at least it wouldn't hurt.

## Side effects

Of course, as with any change of this nature, there stands a risk to backwards compatibility.

I ran a very quick query on SEDE to find any posts on Stack Overflow that contain `[su]` and found no results, but obviously that's a very small portion of the possibilities (any of the currently ~134 sites could link to any of the currently ~134 sites). However, I can't think of a good reason to use syntax like `[so]` outside of a code block, where such formatting doesn't take place anyway.

## Related posts

I just found this other post that asks for some other shortcuts,  [Add a markdown shortcut to Ask a New Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139298/add-a-markdown-shortcut-to-ask-a-new-question), and I agree that that would be useful, but I think inter-site links might be even more useful.