# [link](/) not expanding at all

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks

I wrote this when answering a question:

> `[Meta Stack Exchange](/)`

and I was expecting it'd be expanded to (rendered page)

> `<a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/">Meta Stack Exchange</a>`

but it ended up as

> Meta Stack Exchange

However, if there's anything after the slash, it'll work fine:

> `[Link](/blah)` expands to [Link](/blah)

It makes no sense not to expand a single slash.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247245/allow-comment-markdown-shortcuts-in-meta-questions-and-answers (this will achieve same goal, in a way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround you can just append `?` or `#` which won't have any real effect:

`[Meta Stack Exchange](/?)` → [Meta Stack Exchange](/?)

`[Meta Stack Exchange](/#)` → [Meta Stack Exchange](/#)

#### Update: Correct solution (that adds nothing to the URL)

`[Meta Stack Exchange](/.)` → [Meta Stack Exchange](/.)

Comment: Appending `.` doesn’t add anything to the URL: `[Meta Stack Exchange](/.)` results in: [Meta Stack Exchange](/.)

Comment: @unor Can you explain what a dot does? I know what a question mark or a hash do but not a dot. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: @iBug In the context of file paths and URLs, the period means "current directory", while a double period means "parent directory"

Comment: @unor Well done finding that. When this question was first asked, I thought I tried all the obvious punctuation marks... oops

Comment: But adding a `?` also adds nothing to the URL. It only creates an *empty* HTTP GET response.

Comment: Yes, the period is the correct solution. The question mark and hash tag are copy/paste from the comments of others. Thus, this is a community answer.

Comment: @iBug: "But adding a `?` also adds nothing to the URL." -- This *does* add the `?` to the URL, so you end up at `https://meta.stackexchange.com/?`. If you go with the `.`, you end up at `https://meta.stackexchange.com/`, not at `https://meta.stackexchange.com/.`.