# Is "edit" markdown in the comments a bug or a feature?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I wrote a comment to a question asking the OP to edit his question with more details ([link to my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860866/program-catch-the-arithmetic-exception-and-will-demonstrate-the-finally-block#comment17406452_12860866)). Since the OP is a relatively new member with no editor badge, I phrased my comment as "Click `[edit]`", with the square brackets around the word "edit", and no parenthesized URI following it.

Much to my surprise, "edit" showed up as a hyperlink in the finished comment. But when I clicked that link out of curiosity, I was simply astonished: I did not expect that link to work, and it did! The system brought up the editor for the question.

Here is what I would like to know:

- Is this a bug or a feature<sup>*</sup>?
- If this is a feature, where can I learn more about comment-specific markdown?

---

<sup>*</sup> If it is a bug, that would be the coolest bug I've seen! Please do not fix it :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a feature, just like `[FAQ]` auto-linking to faq entries.

They are all documented on the [comment format page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: That's nice to know! Is there a [faq] for other markdowns available in the comments?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: now linked. :-) Had to find it for you first...

Comment: Thank you very much! These sites really have a lot more stuff than meets the eye, even after almost a year of a relatively active use. Thanks for the quick answer - I'll accept it as soon as the system lets me click the checkmark.