# Automatic community-defined magic links

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

SO already supports automatic magic links inside comments for some pages like stackoverflow.com or the faq. If I wrote [so] or [faq] in a comment, a link to the page would automatically appear.

Since there's a lot of comments that redirect the users to other pages, it would be nice to have a community-driven linking feature - where users can create magic links for popular pages that get linked to often.

Some that come to mind are the meta page on how accepting an answer works, for which we could have an `[accepting]` shortcut, or a shortcut to the C++ book list `[C++books]`.

Comment: I believe the unofficial term for that is ["magic links"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments), no [hot-links](http://www.terrariaonline.com/attachments/ppic-jpg.34558/).

Comment: ... and it looks like the *official* term is ["shorthand links"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ not bug, inform. Anything wrong with that?