# Magic links get broken when quoting a comment in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, chat, api

I tried quoting my [comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/chemistry-text-for-working-professional-non-chemist#comment2121_1202) in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7322700#7322700). The comment used the `[chat]` [magic comment link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000). In the quotation, the link text `Chemistry Chat` became `Stack Exchange Api V2 Chat`

I tried it with a bunch more magic links [on my sandbox](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111/formatting-sandbox-please-test-stuff-here#comment308_112). For reference, the source of the comment is as follows:

```
 [chat]  [ask] [answer] [edit] [faq] [meta-faq] [faq#flagging] [physics.se]
```

[This is the result](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7322784#7322784). The title-text of the `[chat]` link is broken, and most of the link targets are borked.

(I can't use `[meta]` on the formatting sandbox since it's *on* meta, but [here is the result](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1107/why-is-ho-a-dipole/1110#comment3833_1110) of quoting a comment with meta on it on main)

Looks like chat treats the magic links in the quote as if they're *chat* magic links, which work differently.

Fix please?

Comment: How do you quote a comment in chat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a bug in the API, not in chat. The onebox just displays whatever the API returns, and what the API returns is [this](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/comments/2121?site=chemistry&filter=!3zv0S-zw%28-dL-izQe) and [this](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/comments/308?site=meta.chemistry&filter=!3zv0S-zw%28-dL-izQe):

```
{"items": [
    {"body": "<a href=\"http://chat.stackexchange.com\">Stack Exchange Api V2
        Chat</a>  <a href=\"/questions/how-to-ask\">How to Ask</a>
        <a href=\"/questions/how-to-answer\">How to Answer</a> [edit]
        <a href=\"/faq\">faq</a> [meta-faq] <a href=\"/faq#flagging\">faq</a>
        <a href=\"http://physics.stackexchange.com\">Physics</a>"
    }
]}
```

Fixed in the next API build, after which it will work correctly in chat as well.