# Magic link new [about] pages in comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks, magic-links

We already have the ability to have certain links auto-expand in comments as per [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000).

Can the new about pages also be added using the `[about]` format since they are an awesome reference to point new users to along with the FAQ?

What should the link text be? "About $sitename"? "about page"? Something else?

Comment: test: what are you talking [about]? :) failed

Comment: I *really* hope the new quickstart pages will have an auto-expand keyword from the get-go.

Comment: @J.Steen So far I see it deployed to most sites, but there is not auto-expand yet.

Comment: I'll settle for "get-go" being "within a week or two". ;)

Comment: @J. Steen: You mean ["within 6 to 8 weeks"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514).

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn It's been so long since I saw it that I had forgotten about that meme.

Comment: @J. Steen: Don't be silly. 6 to 8 weeks isn't *that* long.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Ba-dump tish.

Comment: @balpha: As for what the link should be, what's wrong with just linkifying the word "about"? That'll match `[faq]`.

Comment: @AlEverett Might be a bit weird in the reading flow, since "about" isn't a noun. I don't have strong opinions on this, but I'd like to hear from the people who would be using this feature a lot.

Comment: @balpha: It could easily be expressed by simply sending someone to look at the [about] page and the [faq] for example.

Comment: @JonEgerton Then post an answer.

Comment: This has been [tag:status-complete]-ed, but I'm missing the pictures mentioned in the bounty ... I really want to see those sloths!

Comment: @JoachimSauer: ok, hang on then...

Comment: [About] time! :)

Comment: How about using [geocities] for that?

Comment: Is the bounty [about] to be awarded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think just having the link as [about] would be fine - this would lead to the comment to the user reading:

"...Please check out the [FAQ] and the [About] page on how to get the most out of the site..."

which would appear as:

"...Please check out the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [About](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) page on how to get the most out of the site..."

It reads ok.

EDIT: The wished for Sloth pics: (afraid I'm not up to hand drawing, so t'interweb will have to provide instead). Anyone else fancy a go?

Pics from [here](http://funnyanimalsa2z.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/funny-sloths-photos.html):

[image: A sloth]

[image: Another sloth]

And lastly (from [here](http://www.newsvine.com/_news/2012/03/01/10563464-all-wrapped-up-baby-sloth-gets-put-in-a-onesie):

Awwww...

[image: Sloth in a Onesie]

Comment: Looks like nobody's objecting to this, hence so be it!

Comment: @balpha So is [about] working yet? Awesome work! Thank you,

Comment: @balpha Oh, I just found this thread. “About” would be completely useless to me, I don't think I'd ever want it. [“questions and answers site” is what I use often](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165625/add-about-to-list-of-magic-links). I'm telling people to read the /about page for a reason, not because it's called “about”, but because of what it explains.

Comment: @Gilles, I see what you mean, but its quite restrictive in how it could be used. Maybe, if it was to be the case, then we could have a standard comment insert function to give the usual canned,"Welcome, see these links" message. (I type some variation on this several times a day at present.)