# Add [about] to list of "magic links"

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Auto-Expand new about pages in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163986/auto-expand-new-about-pages-in-comments)

Now that the [About](http://stackoverflow.com) page is much more educational and has been [launched network-wide](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/about-page-2-0-the-quickstartening/?cb=1), I think I'll be directing people to it rather often.

Can we please have `[about]` added to the list of [Magic Links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/21960) one can use in comments?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I often use links to /about in comments. But the text should not be “About”. A typical use for me is

```
Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [questions and answers site](http://sitename.stackexchange.com/about) …
```

So I would like `[about]` to be a magic link with the visible text “questions and answers site”.