# Add an [about] shortcut for the comment syntax

Tags: feature-request, comments, tour

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Add [about] to list of “magic links”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165625/add-about-to-list-of-magic-links)
>   [Auto-Expand new about pages in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163986/auto-expand-new-about-pages-in-comments)

We already have a few nice [comment shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments), like `[faq]`, `[chat]` or `[meta]`, but there's one missing here.

Since our "About" pages are now *much* better suited for new users than the FAQ, is there a chance we can get `[about]` expanded to the URL of the site's About page?

---

<sub>While we're at it, can we *please* find a proper way to address Meta Stack Overflow? I would have thought it's `[mso]`, `[m.so]`, or even `[meta.so]`, but no, it's `[metaso]` – what?!</sub>