# Can we add the '[about]' or '[tour]' magic comments to chat please?

Tags: feature-request, chat, magic-links

Recently the new ["about" page was rolled out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/were-rolling-out-a-new-quick-start-guide-to-help-new-users-learn-the-basics) and was soon [added to the list of magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163986/magic-link-new-about-pages-in-comments).

However this doesn't seem to work in chat, just comments:

[image]

Could we please expand this to chat?  I use these a lot.

---

I suppose we should update this to `[tour]` now that the /tour page has replaced /about.

<sup>See also: [Can we get help center magic links in chat, just like in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218210/can-we-get-help-center-magic-links-in-chat-just-like-in-comments)</sup>

Comment: I noticed this the other day too.