# Can we get help center magic links in chat, just like in comments?

Tags: feature-request, chat, magic-links

I just noticed that magic links to the help center (`help` and the like) don't work in chat.  Can we fix this? Magic links make it so much easier to help users understand how the site works without having to dig up the full link.

Proof:

[image]

Can this feature be added to chat?

<sup>And while you're at it, you could fix this too: [Can we add the '[about]' or '[tour]' magic comments to chat please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173694/about-magic-link-doesnt-work-in-chat-just-comments)</sup>