# Add a [conduct] "magic link" – similar to [help] and [tour] – to link to the Code of Conduct in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, magic-links, code-of-conduct

I like the [help] and [tour] shortcuts to concisely direct people to a specific section of the help in whatever site I’m commenting on.

Can a [conduct] or similar [magic link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163986/magic-link-new-about-pages-in-comments) to create a proper link to the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) in comments please be added?

Comment: Note: comments are re-rendered on page render, unlike posts, which have their HTML rendering cached after every update, so your comment will linkify the two latter magic links as soon as the site is updated.

Comment: Don't forget a [mcve].

Comment: +1 [conduct] or [coc] would be fantastic, and I want to be able to use these.