# If I write [edit] inside a comment, it creates a link to edit the question, why?

Tags: discussion, comments, markdown-rendering

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14646273/569101), I posted a comment (the 4th one in the comments list).

I then made an edit, but I wanted to make sure that people see that there is an edit, so I wrote at the end of my comment `[edit]` and the rest of the message.

When I submitted the changes to my comment, I noticed that my `[edit]` just got converted to a link to the question edition page.

Is that a bug or feature ?

[image]

Comment: this is a test, edit link: [edit]

Comment: That is mentioned in the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: You don't need to alert people you made an edit to a comment. The little pencil icon after the time of posting does that for you.

Comment: @AlEverett I know that, but in this case I wanted to indicate the first text and the edited part.

Comment: -1 lack of freehand circles :P

Comment: @j0k And you don't need to do that.  They can look at the revision history if they want to know.

Comment: @Servy Where can I find the link to see the comment revision history?

Comment: @j0k Oh, I thought you were referring to an edit in the post, nvm then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a feature: [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000).

Comment: Hm. I never knew that. Those might come in handy some day... *ahem* [ask] [answer] [faq]

Comment: I never knew that too, thanks