# Are there more things like [faq]?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, magic-links

When you type `[faq]` in a comment, it resolves into a link to the site's FAQ. I was just wondering if there are more short-style links to commonly used things. I don't remember how I found out about the FAQ one and I can't find a list of them anywhere.

And if they don't exist, can we add more? For example one I would use often would be `[jsFiddle]` Or `[sscce]`.

Comment: Those are called "magic links" and the definitive list is in this answer: [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000)

Comment: @AlEverett thanks, you can post that as an answer.

Comment: what.. you can do this ? [faq] wow I always did [F.A.Q] + (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk: You're welcome.