# Add the capability to turn non-answer answers from new users into comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, new-users

The issue of what to do hen a new user posts a comment as an answer because they don't have enough reputation to comment [has been discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206889/what-to-do-when-reviewing-not-an-answer-from-a-new-user-without-enough-reputat) for scenarios where the comment doesn't really add value, but what about scenarios were the comment is insightful or important to understanding the question? Not only do I feel bad flagging those answers, I feel like it's not really entirely productive to delete them. Would it be possible to give reviewers the capability to convert such answers to comments instead of just flagging them?

I suppose this might have the potential to be overused (i.e. people could turn things that really weren't intended as comments into comments).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators already have this ability.

If you flag the answer as *not an answer* a moderator will be able to take this action.

If you want be more explicit you can flag the answer for moderator attention and directly ask for the answer to be converted into a comment, but it's usually not necessary: moderators know what they are doing and, in case it's appropriate, they will probably convert it in any case.

Comment: Generally we still don't. Converting new users' answers to comments just provides a pathway for them to post comments which we do not want to provide. For the record, I have never once converted an answer to a comment for a new user.