# Privileges magic link for comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, help-center, magic-links

In [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) a number of 'magic links' were added.  These translate things such as [help/on-topic] into https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic in the comments (rendered as "help center").

With the loss of the privileges link from the header it can be (slightly) harder to instruct people where to find this information.

Could [help/privileges] be made to link to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges (as appropriate for the site) when used in comments?