# Be able to specify a particular room in the chat magic link

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, hyperlinks

From [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) there are several very useful magic links that show up in comments.  In particular, there's `[chat]`.

> [chat] – link to the current site's chat site, the link text being "{site name} Chat".

That's great.  However, sometimes a site will have multiple rooms.  This may get confusing which room you want the person to go to.

Make a `[chat/#]` magic link where `#` is the room number.  This would expand to the name of the room.

For example, `[chat/21]` would look up and find `The Whiteboard` while `[chat/35]` would be `The Bridge`.  This would also be a link to the room itself, rather than the general "site rooms" where `[chat]` currently targets.

This would make it easier to direct a person to the proper room without having to specify the `[The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/)` as something in a comment - which is a bit of typing (or C&P) and eats up valuable characters.

Comment: Wow, I was always under the misguided assumption that if used on [programmers.se], it would lead directly to The Whiteboard, and The Water Cooler on [workplace.se], etc. It doesn't. That is a bit counter-productive!