# Can a community have its own internal magic links?

Tags: feature-request, support, comments, magic-links

I'm talking about [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/260388), which are very useful while posting comments. We frequently use `[tour]` , `[help]`, `[ask]`, `[ans]` etc. while introducing new users about How Stack Exchange works.

On Hinduism Stack Exchange, we educate new users about our [guidelines](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/12713). Though we have also [included](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/876/277) a link to that page in the new answer pop-up, we still frequently need to refer new users to the [guidelines](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/12713).

So, can we (Hinduism Stack Exchange) have a `[guidelines]` magic link  pointing to [that meta question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/)? Another example is `[faq]` referring the [Community FAQ Index](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478/277) instead of referring to the already having `[tour]` magic link.

More generally, can a community have its own magic links? Presently by this question, I'm thinking of having *internal* magic links within the community or SE network unlike [previously posted FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244720/site-specific-magic-comment-links) that introduces or lists most of the external links.

Comment: Probably they can't, adding tag for feature request as well.

Comment: I don't see why this is not possible, Stack Overflow has an [mcve] magic link that does not work here.

Comment: Btw, [that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244720/260388) discuss magic links outside of Stack Exchange whereas [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/260388) deals with links within the Network.