# Target Linkable Help Content

Tags: feature-request, comments, off-topic, magic-links

I was just looking around to respond (via comment) to an off-topic post on StackOverflow and wanted to point a user to a direct paragraph as to "why" the Question was off topic. What I propose (and correct me if I am wrong) is that all points on the documentation that are headers, lists items etc be linkable (even by browser hash tags).

This should make it easier for users to directly link to pages to help users compose clearer questions. An example would be:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Any of the points in the section **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:** would be useful to be directly linked to.

I hope this hasn't been asked before.

**Edit**

Just to clarify I am not requesting a link to a page but a section within the page. So this means I could go to `https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic#specific_reason` where specific reason is a part\subsection of the help page itself.

Comment: If you type `[help/on-topic]` you get the [help/on-topic] in comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments)

Comment: @MichaelT I never knew that :) Still would be nice to quickly link to a specific part of a help topic

Comment: I wanted to add a bounty here, but it seems I cannot :-(

Comment: @Anthon the post is protected by community however I reckon they could do a better job with linking content easier.