# Extend comment "magic links" syntax to allow arbitrary link text

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, magic-links

The [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) are awesome.

How much more awesome would it be to be able to make a comment linking to one of the URLs covered by a magic link, but *with custom text*?

Since the square-bracket link type isn't included in the mini-markdown used for comments, it could be stolen for this purpose.

Comment text like

```
Please [add that information][edit] to the body 
of your post rather than using comments.
```

or

```
Please [include the shortest possible amount of code that
demonstrates the problem you see][mcve].
```

would convert to

```
Please [add that information](http://{SITE}.stackexchange.com/posts/{ID}/edit) 
to the body of your post rather than using comments.
```

and

```
Please [include the shortest possible amount of code that
demonstrates the problem you see](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
```

for example.

Comment: You may be interested in my [Custom “magic links” for comments](http://stackapps.com/q/6650/26088) userscript :)