# Can we have magic links for comments that link to help center of the site we're recommending?

Tags: feature-request, comments, help-center, magic-links, referrals

I love using [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/200235) for referring someone to a more appropriate stack.

However, if I'm recommending that someone check out another Stack, often times I want to give them a direct link to their help center, rather than the main page. This is especially true when I'm suggesting that someone *might get a good answer on another stack, but they don't yet conform to **that site's** guidelines* (and they *definitely* don't conform to the current site's guidelines).

[We currently have:](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

> `[help]`, `[help/on-topic]`, `[help/dont-ask]`, `[help/behavior]`, `[ask]`, `[answer]` and `[meta-help]` – link to frequently visited pages of the help center. Link text is "help center" (capitalization is respected). All links point to the main site.
>
> `[so]`, `[pt.so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metase]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – link to the given site. Link text is the site name.
>
> `[something.se]` – link to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name. Use `[ubuntu.se]` for Ask Ubuntu.

**I'd like to also have:**

> `[something.se/help]`, `[something.se/help/on-topic]`, `[something.se/help/dont-ask]`, `[meta-help]` - As above, but links to those pages on the other stacks we're referring to.
>
> `[so/help]`, `[pt.so/help]`, `[su/help]`, `[sf/help]` - All the same for these sites too, obviously; I don't know exactly the best way to phrase the markdown help text.

<sub>I removed `help/behavior` on purpose because I doubt anyone would be referring someone to the behavior page on another Stack.</sub>

Comment: May as well add `help/behavior` because why not?