# Add a magic comment link for help/formatting

Tags: feature-request, comments, help-center, magic-links

The [magic comment links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92060/203101) are extremely useful. However, the one page I most often find myself linking to in comments is `$SITE/help/formatting`. Unfortunately, `[help/formatting]` doesn't work.

Could we have `[help/formatting]` expand to https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting (where `http://meta.stackexchange.com` is replaced by the current site's URL) just like `[help/on-topic]` and `[help/dont-ask]` do? Ideally, the text shown would be `formatting tools` but the standard `Help Center` would do if that's too complex.

That way, I could just write

> Please use the [help/formatting] to enter code correctly.

And have it rendered as

> Please use the [formatting tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to enter code correctly.

Comment: Yes, please, I want that! My auto-comments want that! The WORLD <s>wants</s> *needs* that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also made a userscript for this sort of thing.

It allows you to define your own custom magic links.

### You can get it [at StackApps](https://stackapps.com/q/6650/26088)

For this particular case, the link you would define would be:

```
magicLinks['help/formatting formatting tools'] = '$BASEURL$/help/formatting';
```

Or relatively:

```
magicLinks['help/formatting formatting tools'] = '/help/formatting';
```

That will make more sense when you visit the Stack Apps post! :)

---

BTW an extra feature you get with this userscript is that you can make magic links that can have **custom text** -- so you could say something like [visit the formatting tools][help/formatting] to automatically add the link to the formatting tools but with your own text! :)

Comment: Nice, any particular reason to use base url? Why not relative links?

Comment: @nicael hmmm; honestly didn't think of that but it should work with just using relatively! Edited to reflect that :) thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've made a user script which converts your `[help/formatting]` links into the desired `[formatting tools](/help/formatting)`, once you submit your comment or an edit to your comment.

> [image]

Be sure to [try it out](https://greasyfork.org/ru/scripts/13770-help-formattin)!

Comment: Thanks for this. I went with the other solution since it provides arbitrary link text.