# Magic links are not localized in app

Tags: bug, android-app, ios-app, localization, magic-links

My [comment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660563/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-error-code-%D0%B2-boost#comment951886_660563) to the post contains a magic link `[mcve]`.
On the web this link translated to Russian:

> [image: web]

But in app this link remains untranslated:

> [image: ios-app]

Same for android app:

> [image: android]

I think any of [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/339911) should use localized text version for in-app usage like it done for web.

Just noticed that immediately after posting via app comment looks localized:

> [image: rus-im]

But after refreshing it becomes English:

> [image: eng-refresh]

- App Version: 1.6.5.3
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

---

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (1710300506712