# Add data.SE style “magic links” to questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, magic-links

When writing comments or using chat, users can use "[magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92060/351462)" as markdown shortcuts.

- `[help]` – [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help)
- `[tour]` – [Tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour)
- `[chat]` – [Meta Stack Exchange Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/)
- `[answer]` – [How To Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)
- `[meta.se]` – [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)
- `[something.se]` – something.stackexchange.com (if it exists)

Currently, these shortcuts are only available in comments and chat. Using them anywhere else will have no effect.

**It would be [helpful] to have access to these shortcuts when writing [questions] and [answers].**

Comment: Yes. I'm so lazy and I refer to other SEs generically in meta posts all the time... I would really love the last one, particularly.

Comment: Any examples of how these would be useful in questions or answers?