# Why do magic links work only in comments?

Tags: discussion, support, magic-links

Is there a specific reason why [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/243091) such as [so], [meta.se], etc. do not work in questions and answers, too? Is this by design? They would be handy, especially in the meta sites.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markdown shorthand for Stack Exchange sites in questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290413/markdown-shorthand-for-stack-exchange-sites-in-questions-and-answers) (also see its duplicate, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298810/1017231)

Comment: @bobble no, it's not duplicate. It's legit to ask *why* instead of asking to change something. It's different, and with different answers.

Comment: Found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366740/why-do-magic-links-that-work-in-comments-not-work-in-posts), which could be duplicate but somehow miss the point and asked in a different way, which got answer which doesn't really answer the actual question. Since the answer is official from SE staff, it pretty much "seal the deal", i.e. chances for another answer there are pretry much zero. Bottom line, related but not fitting as duplicate as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry I found that question and answer, too, but it doesn't answer my question; basically it just discusses a case in which OP used the wrong syntax for links and got an unexpected result.