# Magic link for MathOverflow in chat and comments

Tags: support, comments, chat, magic-links, mathoverflow

I can link to many Stack Exchange sites with syntax like `[so]` or `[math.se]`. Now that MathOverflow is a member for Stack Exchange is there a similar markdown link?

Answer (score 5):

Site-specific magic links take the site URL name add, ".se" and put the entire thing in square brackets.

So, if the site URL is cooking.stackexchange.com, you get [cooking.se] which, in comments and chat (but not in posts), will convert to a link.

Now, Math Overflow is mathoverflow.net *but* there is a redirect to it from mathoverflow.stackexchange.com, which gives you the information you need so, as animuson said, the magic link for Math Overflow is [mathoverflow.se].

The guide to Magic Links is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000); a less complete version is (more or less) part of the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) - notably, it [lacks a MathOverflow entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331106/295232).

Comment: I was unaware of the alternate `mathoverflow.stackexchange.com` domain. Thanks for the infor. On the other hand, `[mo]` would be much more convenient.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you... this is a support question, not a FR... maybe ask a new question? I'd love IPS to be `[ips.se]` because it's **way** shorter than `[interpersonal.se]`... but I don't know that it's a good use of dev time to add these. As is, I think they're created by default.

Comment: Yes, my previous comment could be a feature request.

Comment: It seems similar thing works for per-site-metas, such as [interpersonal.meta.se] obtained using `[interpersonal.meta.se]`. I wasn't able to find magic link for MathOverflow Meta: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51378317#51378317. Is there one? (I wasn't sure whether to ask here in a comment or whether to post a separate question on this.)