# Add shorthand links for MathOverflow and all non-English Stack Overflow sites to comment formatting help page

Tags: feature-request, comments, magic-links, editing-help

The [editing help for comments](/editing-help#comment-formatting) currently lists a few shorthand links which can be used to link to other sites:

- `[so]`, `[pt.so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metase]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – link to the given site. Link text is the site name.
- `[something.se]` – link to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name. Use `[ubuntu.se]` for Ask Ubuntu.

[Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) is the only non-English Stack Overflow site listed, but `[es.so]`, `[ja.so]` and `[ru.so]` work as well. Can these be added? Furthermore, if `[ubuntu.se]` is listed as an exception, `[mathoverflow.se]` should be added as well. Not many people know that's a valid alias.

Also, it makes sense to rearrange the bullets a bit. The two discussed above should be next to each other, since they serve the same purpose: links to another Q&A site. They should probably be next to `[main]`, `[meta]` and `[chat]`, while the one about `[ask]`, `[answer]` (both link to Help Center pages) should be next to the one starting with `[help]`.