# For those that don't know about them: Comment shortcuts are handy

Tags: discussion, comments

I've seen people that don't know about these, so I thought I'd post this just a heads up.

There are comment shortcuts like `[edit]`, `[mcve]`, and `[tour]` that allow you to quickly link to useful pages in comments. `[edit]` links to the editing page for that question, `[mcve]` becomes [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and `[tour]` becomes [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

---

You can use them pretty simply:

- Please post an [mcve] of the problem.

  - Please post an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.
- Please [edit] that information into your question

  - Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/QUESTIONID/edit) that information into your question.

---

They're mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) in the help, and are discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) on Meta.

---

I know that especially on Meta, a lot of people will know about these. I just thought I'd mention them because I occasionally see people writing things like `[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)` in comments, which isn't very efficient.

Comment: How do you know these people have written `[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)` in their comments instead of just `[tour]`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The Android app shows the raw text of comments if you copy them.

Comment: @Carc, hey, that's nice, I wasn't aware of that. Too bad the apps are discontinued. Here is [a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92060/164403) with the complete (AFAICT) vocabulary.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi They're still more usable than the mobile site 

Comment: Or rather "it's". The SO app wasn't great either. The SE app though, despite being super buggy, is still miles ahead of the mobile site.