# Magic link capitalization

Tags: feature-request, magic-links, capitalization

Since the current [Stack Exchange guideline](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#buttons-and-links) requires capitalization for links, should we also capitalize (I think we should) the result of [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/339911)?

E.g., hence using `[edit]` will result in `Edit` instead of `edit`. To reflect the same appearance with the actual "Edit" link under the post body.

Comment: Most of them respect capitalization already, right? `[edit]:` [edit] `[Edit]:` [Edit]

Comment: [Edit] is still possible.

Comment: @zcoop98 oh ... I completely forgot about this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To address the feature-request aspects of this: no, please don't make any of these links capitalized by default. They're often used in sentences, like:

> Please don't add additional information to your question via comments; instead, [edit] it into the post.

Or on Stack Overflow (where this expands to "[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"):

> Please add a [mre] to your post so that we can debug it. As is, it's hard to tell what's causing that error.

If they were capitalized, they'd be out of place in the sentence.

Answer (score 10):

According to this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/339911) to [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060) magic links already support letter case:

> Characters within the magic links can be any mix of upper and lower case. Some, but not all, of the magic links will respect the case used in the magic link and use the same case for the link text. This is noted in the entry for those which respect case.

So we can always use `[Edit]` for "Edit", or `[edit]` for "edit".

Thanks to @zcoop98 for the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362958/magic-link-capitalization?noredirect=1#comment1211271_362958).