# Why do magic links, that work in comments, not work in posts?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, magic-links, posts

DSP.SE

^ is actually

```
[DSP.SE](dsp.stackexchange.com/)
```

As a comment, it renders, but it changes text and inserts the URL separately:

[image]

What's the deal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You aren't entering a valid link, so it's being converted to plain text. `dsp.stackexchange.com/` is not a proper URL for linking to the site and, if rendered, would actually end up linking to `https://meta.stackexchange.com/dsp.stackexchange.com/` instead, because it would be interpreted by the browser as a relative path at best.

It needs to be `https://dsp.stackexchange.com/`.

But you also don't need to type out the URL either. As you've noticed, `[DSP.SE]` is a [magic identifier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) that will automatically link to the appropriate site.

Comment: `//dsp.stackexchange.com` *should* work too.

Comment: //dsp.stackexchange.com works in posts, but comments have more basic markdown.