# Magic link for commenting cross posted questions for maintaining one copy

Tags: feature-request, cross-posting

I've seen many cross-posted questions occur again and again. It is okay that users urgently seek answers for their problems. The problem is we need to write and add the link of the consensus them about keeping one copy. Consensus;

- [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/403350)

**Suggestion:**

the magic link `[cross]` should expand as (or a better version)

> Could you maintain one copy of your question? Please see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/403350) for details.

This will make the commenting easier since at least there is a find, copy and paste of the consensus...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The magic link [cross] should expand as (or a better version)
>
> > Could you maintain one copy of your question? Please see Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site? for details.

This is not how magic links work. Magic links aren't complete comments, they are just a short way to link to a specific link, so you can save some characters when writing a comment. See for example [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment1063671_325826) in the formatting sandbox, where magic links like  `[help/on-topic]` shows up as a link named 'help center' but nothing more. The benefit of this is that you don't have to look for the specific link, but you also can have more freedom when writing the rest of your comments.

Then, looking at the beginning of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/369802) and the [comment there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments#comment235961_94000) illustrating the use of magic links, I can see there's apparently a `[FAQ#flagging]` syntax, which shows up as a link named 'FAQ'. While that magic link links to /help/flagging, I think a similar syntax should be used (if possible) to link to other FAQ articles.

Then, one final point would be to use the whole word. So 'cross-posting' instead of the shorter, but less clear, 'cross'. This is mostly a personal preference I guess, though I would think it's clearer because now we know we're linking to something about cross-posting and not to something about cross-selling or cross-fit.

So, I propose the magic link should be `[FAQ#cross-posting]`, it should show up as "[FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/369802)", and it should link the user to [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/369802).

An example comment would then end up being written like:

> Could you maintain one copy of your question? Please see our [FAQ#cross-posting] for details.

And it would render as:

> Could you maintain one copy of your question? Please see our [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/369802) for details.

---

<sub>PS: if you do not want to write entire comments all the time, there's a userscript you can use: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se). But magic links should not be 'abused' for that.</sub>

Comment: And, thanks for the PS. Didn't know that.