# "Magic Links" displayed text ambiguous in some cases

Tags: feature-request, comments, help-center, magic-links

The help-center ["magic links" for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) such as `[help/on-topic]`, `[help/dont-ask]` and `[help/behavior]` currently have the ambiguous (and poorly capitalized) display text of "help center", "help center", and "help center", respectively.

These shortcuts would be easier to use and convey the point more effectively if they instead displayed the actual name of the target article, such as "*What topics can I ask about here?*", "*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*" and "*What kind of behavior is expected of users?*", respectively.

I'm not sure which other magic links also display equally unhelpful text.

---

Just for fun, I checked their usage on Stack Overflow:

In the last 12 months **665,731** users commented **5,622,210** times (8½ comments each).
During the same period, **2,704** users (0.4%) used "magic links" in **70,603** comments (0.01%).

Hmm, I suppose that based on negligible usage, my above request is probably unlikely to be fulfilled anytime soon.
Ah well.

---

### Last 12 months usage on Stack Overflow

| Magic link | No. of uses in last 12 months on SO |
| --- | --- |
| [edit] | 24233 |
| [mcve] | 14093 |
| [mre] | 10785 |
| [ask] | 9011 |
| [tour] | 5070 |
| [answer] | 2006 |
| [help] | 1695 |
| [example] | 1473 |
| [help/on-topic] | 514 |
| [so] | 485 |
| [repro] | 342 |
| [su] | 296 |
| [meta] | 153 |
| [reprex] | 120 |
| [sf] | 95 |
| [main] | 62 |
| [chat] | 35 |
| [ubuntu.se] | 34 |
| [meta.se] | 29 |
| [pt.so] | 24 |
| [es.so] | 19 |
| [help/dont-ask] | 12 |
| [ru.so] | 11 |
| [se] | 3 |
| [about] | 2 |
| [ja.so] | 1 |
| [a51] | 0 |
| [help/behavior] | 0 |
| [mathoverflow.se] | 0 |
| [meta-about] | 0 |
| [meta-help] | 0 |
| [metase] | 0 |
| [meta-tour] | 0 |

Comment: I wish I could use the “on topic” page more often, but I can never remember the `[help/on-topic]` thing and of course I know that the link won’t say “What topics can I ask about here?” but only “help center”. `[on-topic]` or something like that would be a lot better.