# Can we change the link text for Comment Shorthands?

Tags: discussion, comments, magic-links

One of my <sup>[+ SO's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376426/magic-links-displayed-text-ambiguous-in-some-cases)</sup> most-used [Comment shorthand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) is the `[edit]` link:

> [edit]
>
> Link to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e. `/posts/{id}/edit`.
> Link text is `"edit"` (capitalization is respected).

---

Sometimes, this `edit` is not the correct word to use when commenting something like:

> Please improve the post by [edit]**ing** ...

Real-World example can be found in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74888597/cant-solve-advent-of-code-task-3-with-python):

[image]

---

There does not seem a way of changing the text, I've tried thinks like

```
[editing]
[editing](edit)
```

The only way of getting the desired outcome is by manually copying the post-id and use a markdown url:

```
[editing](/posts/385115/edit)
```

But this is something I've never done, nor encountered in the wild, so don't think people will take those steps and just leave it as `[edit]ing`.

---

Could we -

1. Add a way to manually overwrite the text of the shorthands
   <sub>and/or</sub>
2. Add aliases with more variants like `editing` and `edited`

---

This question is not limited to `[edit]`, the same goes for thinks like

- `[ask]ing`
- `[answer]ing`
- `[chat]ting`

Comment: Something like [editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/385115/edit) ? basically doing it the long way

Comment: Yea, even tho it's not that much effort, I tend to keep it as [edit]ing since typing (and copying post-id) like: `/posts/{id}/edit` doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: The entire word really should be in the link. When I read the comment with VoiceOver, it says "…as —edit link—ing since…" which is weird and mildly confusing.

Comment: Trivial workaround: change the wording of the comment to match the magic link, e.g. instead of "Please improve the post by editing", change to "Please edit the post in order to improve it", and you can use the magic link without any issues.

Comment: Thats a viable option, but I think being able to change the tekst will gives us way more options for comment, also useful for tools that paste default comments like [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments). Same goes for [mre], sometimes emphasising eg 'minimal' could be useful: `[*m*re]`

Comment: That example question has now been deleted.

Comment: Related: [Stack Exchange magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) (posts, comments, and chat) and [shortcuts in URLs, incl. shortcut for the current user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332237/documentation-for-stack-exchange-engine-urls/332251#332251) (`current` instead of the user ID).

Comment: A similar one for the current post (for use in comments) as for the current user could solve the problem of having to know the absolute post ID (thus better suited for canned comments).