# Is there a collection of popular/helpful comment responses for questions?

Tags: discussion, comments

I would like to quickly respond to a question with a comment such as "Your questions is not [clear](https://example.com)" or "Please include some code" or "This question belongs on Stack Overflow". Where can I find such a collection?

Comment: I think there is a userscript for this, don't know its name though. You might want to check out [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/).

Comment: @Luuklag It's called "AutoReviewComments" and it's no longer being maintained.

Comment: Just a copy paste will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Natively, there are a couple of shorthand links you can include in comments called "Magic Links". A list of all supported magic links is available [in this Meta SE Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92060/622284). These are useful in speeding up the *manual* commenting process, though.

What you're probably looking for is a userscript, which requires a script manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/). As Sonic mentioned [in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379976/stackoverflow-is-there-a-collection-that-contains-popular-comment-responses-fo#comment1267634_379976), there's a userscript called [AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) that adds a simple "auto" button next to the Add-comment modal when adding a comment, and allows you to select from a list of pretyped comments. However, that userscript's main repository is no longer being maintained.

Some users have forked the main repository and made their own, updating it when necessary. I personally like using a fork maintained by [Machavity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2370483/machavity), a current Stack Overflow moderator. That fork is [available here](https://github.com/machavity/SE-AutoReviewComments/blob/master/dist/autoreviewcomments.user.js) ([install link](https://github.com/machavity/SE-AutoReviewComments/raw/master/dist/autoreviewcomments.user.js)). You can adjust the templates to fit your personal style or add new ones in accordance with your needs, but Machavity's fork has a good pool to choose from already.

Answer (score 2):

I have extracted these from [Machavity's script](https://github.com/machavity/SE-AutoReviewComments/blob/master/dist/autoreviewcomments.user.js)

- It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!
- This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!
- Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.
- Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.
- This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.
- Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.
- If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.
- If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.
- This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.
- The tags you were using are not appropriate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)