# Add magic link for image of code/data/errors

Tags: feature-request, comments, images, magic-links

I just read about magic links for the first time from [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments). The accepted answer had a good amount of useful magic links to help articles such as `[mcve]`, `[ask]`, and `[answer]`, but one thing that I found notably missing was a magic link to [the canonical Meta Stack Overflow post for images of code, data, and errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). I think that having a new magic link for this is important considering how often it is needed. It would also be nice if it could expand into the full canonical link and comment if it is the only thing posted in a comment. For example this comment:

```
[image-of-code]
```

should be automatically expanded to this:

```
[Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
```

The canonical link is Meta Stack Overflow, but I suspect that this would be useful for any community that handles code or data, not just Stack Overflow. Can this be added as a magic link?

Comment: There are no magic links directed to specific meta posts. Magic links are, so far, all relative to the site you're on. I don't really think it's worth breaking this convention for this. It's hardly useful outside SO and even where it is, it's probably a bad form to just point to MSO. Instead just bookmark/save the link for easy reference or make a canned comment with it.

Comment: You don't need a magic link, or a comment. Flag the question as needing debugging details instead.