# Can we get an [ai-policy] magic link?

Tags: feature-request, policy, magic-links, generative-ai

Now that sites have [AI policies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy), it seems like we would benefit from a magic link, like `[ai-policy]`, linking to the site's respective help page.

I tested this just now, but it didn't work, and it's not listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) so I don't believe this feature exists yet.  So...

**Question**: Can we get an [ai-policy] magic link?

Comment: As a workaround until this is implemented, you can use `[ai-policy](/help/ai-policy)` to get the following: [ai-policy](/help/ai-policy). From my answer on the related FR on MSO: [Quick link to AI policy in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427725)